# How to easily remember TLS options with postfix and dovecot?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, tls

Specifically I am studying for the LFCE exam and am having trouble remembering all the TLS options I need to add to the postfix/main.cf file which are:

```
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/spool/postfix/smtpd_tls_cache
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
```

Storing all that in my head is quite difficult, is there anywhere on the system where I can easily find these options for reference?

I've hunted around for a README in the `/usr/shars/docs/*` folder but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS run in terminal;

```
cat /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.tls
```

This should give you the contents of `/usr/share/postfix/main.cf.tls` which is;

```
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
```

to check contents of of `/usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz` run;

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz | less
```

or

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz | grep -i smtpd_tls
```

Also you can grep for '`tls_random_source`' separately...

to grep specific parts of the readme file as per your interest

```
#Additionally you can run;

postconf -d | grep -i smtpd_tls
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the manpage: [`man 5 postconf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/postconf.5.html).